# Woocommerce dropdown selection not updating image associated with each variation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Wordpress Site using Woocommerce:

When a user selects a variation via dropdown, the image is not updating to the newly selected image. I hope my description is clear enough. Can upload some images if need be. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: hello! This could be because of other JavaScript files blocking the display, try to disable all plugins and check again, enable one by one and keep checking. If it doesn't work, Link me to your product page so I investigate it myself.

Comment: Here's one example. https://wyrmwoodgaming.com/products/wyrmwood-logo-dice/ I disabled all recent plug-ins and it did not impact it. I'll test shutting all plug ins too, but I figured I should have linked to a page with the issue in the question, so here it is.

Comment: Having only woocommerce plug-in activated results in the same lack of functionality

Comment: Looks very likely this is an issue with our theme having outdated files. Trying to follow tutorials now.

Comment: Theme was going to be my next suggestion, especially if you just updated to WooCommerce 2.5. In the WooCommerce->System Status>Tools you can enable "Template Debug Mode" to disable your theme's templates. Also, try contacting your theme's author.